# Embed soundcloud widget and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, soundcloud

I'm trying to get embedded widgets to work on IE8.
I've read that the embed widget now only is the html5 widget but that it will fallback to a flash widget. I've set up an environment with ie8 and flash installed but all I get is a grey soundcloud logo and some js errors. No flash from what I can tell. It's hard to find any more infromation about this so I hope that maybe someone here knows!?

Thanks

Comment: "some js errors" ok...

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 11:00:29 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 40776
Code: 0
URI: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/assets/widget-02866b43.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 3
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/163802730&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 11:01:55 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 40776
Code: 0
URI: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/assets/widget-02866b43.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 3
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/163802730&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true

Answer (score 1):

from soundcloud support:

Thanks for writing in about this and sorry you're having trouble getting your embeds to work on IE8. Unfortunately we no longer support the flash widget and this means we're unable to troubleshoot any errors that may be occurring.

Also, as it stands, the new SoundCloud has minimum system requirements. These system requirements correspond with what browser and OS versions are still being supported by Apple and Microsoft. By doing this, we can invest our resources and manpower into creating the best user experience possible -- while still ensuring that our updates are also compatible with what hardware and software partners can support us with. This means that we can speak to browser and OS developers and have them be able to help assist us with any needs we may have with future updates. As they do not support some OS and browsers anymore, we also are unable to as we move forward with the platform.

I hope that helps to clarify things further, but please let me know if you have any further questions or concerns.